# Typescript in SPFX breaks on using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, spfx

So,
I am using OOB spfx project generated by yo sharepoint generator  version 1.13.1 and react-router-dom 6.2.1 and typescript Version 4.5.4.

Everytime i do a gulp build tsc throws this error....did anyone got this working?

**[16:04:24] Error - [tsc] node_modules/react-router/index.d.ts(151,74): error TS1110: Type expected.
[16:04:24] Error - [tsc] node_modules/react-router/index.d.ts(151,83): error TS1005: '}' expected.
[16:04:24] Error - [tsc] node_modules/react-router/index.d.ts(151,94): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
[16:04:24] Error - [tsc] node_modules/react-router/index.d.ts(151,96): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.
[16:04:24] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 3.85 s**

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue as well. It looks like the answer from Microsoft is "don't": https://blog.mastykarz.nl/build-multi-page-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-react/

> When building SharePoint Framework web parts you might need to implement multiple views in your web part. When switching between the different views it is essential that you don't modify the URL in the browser's address bar which could render undesired behavior in other components present on the page. When building web parts using React, one way to implement multiple views in a web part is by conditionally showing the different components that represent the different views.

It appears Microsoft don't like you manipulating the URL to achieve routing within your SPFx app. Instead they're suggesting that you use internal state to define the view you show your user.